# How to return Page<Map<String, Object>> from REST endpoint in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have this endpoint

```
@GetMapping("/list")    
public Page<Map<String, Object>> getRecordList(
        @PageableDefault(size = 10) Pageable page,
        RecordSearchParams searchParams
) throws SQLException {
    var val = recordService.getRecordList(page, searchParams, false);
    return val;
}
```

Using this endpoint gives error

```
2023-07-12 14:37:16,931 [http-nio-8555-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] [] [oid:,cid:] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3ReplicationProtocol]] with root cause
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3ReplicationProtocol and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl["content"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap["information_field_uuids"]->org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray["resultSet"]->org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet["statement"]->org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement["connection"]->org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection["queryExecutor"]->org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl["replicationProtocol"])
```

How can i fix this? Response is Map<String, Object> because All the values and types are defined on the runtime by the user based on search params. It effectively represents a variable column object.

The DBquery that gets data is in the formar of

```
List<T> tableRows = jdbcTemplate.query("""
                            some very very complicated and long SQL""",
                sqlParameters,
                new ColumnMapRowMapper()
        );
```

One of the columns returned is a PGArry. I have a conversion service for it. But it seems if i Dont map it directly do a spesific typed object it just wont do anything... But i cant define a spesific object as the result set will have variable amount of columns. And the Page<> Object is from `org.springframework.data.domain`

Comment: What are you returning in the first place? Seems like some postgresql type instead of a regular map.

Comment: Im using ColumnMapRowMapper it is the same thing jdvc queryForList uses. I just have to do it explicitly ro fit in with the rest of the setup we have. Cant just use QueryForList.

Comment: I think i found the issue... But i dont know how to fix it... 1 value returned is a PGArray i have a conversion service for PGArray -> List<UUID> but since this is Map<String,Object> it doesent know what to do with it... Can i somehow tell it what to do or perhabs create a Java Record that can have vairable amount of fields ?

Comment: Well i doubt it does what you think it does. As it clearly indicates that there are custom PostgreSQL classes in there. Please show the code that you are calling. Also which `Page` object does this concern.

Comment: You need to extend the rowmapper for this specific case to convert it to an array or list.

Comment: Got a lucky break. It turns out that the field causing the issue is not needed in the response, only during filtering. So i can just remove it before i return the page.